# NHibernate session, saveorupdate, save

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a problem saving objects with NHibernate. The report variable below has NO changes, but NHibernate throws exception below:

**a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: 262, of entity: xxx.Report**

```
 pulic void SaveReport(Report report)
    {
         using (ISession session = NH.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {

            var childReport = session.QueryOver<Report>()
           .Where(x => x.ReportParent.Id == report.Id)
           .Fetch(x => x.Children).Eager
  .List().Distinct().ToList(); -- [1] refers to the line starting with .List()

           --[2]  report.Children = report.Children;

              session.SaveOrUpdate(report);
              transaction.Commit();

                    }
      }


          class Report
          {
            public virtual int Id { get; set; }
            public virtual IList<Report> Children { get; set; }
           public virtual Report ReportParent { get; set; }
          }
```

If line [1] is commented out, no exception, but I need to make changes to the report variable before save it. For example, use the line below on line [2]:

```
          report.Children = report.Children;
```

**UPDATE**: The Report is loaded outside the SaveReport method using other session, and session.dispose() has been called.

Could anyone please tell me

1) why NHibernate throws exception even report variable has no changes,

2) Why no exception when line [1] is commented out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The obvious question: was the `report` detached from the session by which it was retrieved?

Comment: The Report is loaded outside the SaveReport method using other session.

Answer (score 1):

After your comment: you enter a `Report` object that probably is still attached to the session by which is was retrieved. You have to detach it from that session first (`Session.Evict`).

Comment: but session.dispose() has been called on the session by which the report object was retrieved, which means that that session should be disposed.